# How to get and display dialog textbox values in report format in GWT?

Tags: gwt, textbox, dialog

I am writing one small dialog box with multiple textboxes, and it contains input fields. I would like to show user's input values like a report or something for all entered values in a list in another dialog.

Here is my code snippet where I set label when user inputs values and presses Button. But when user adds some more additional values in a textbox, would it be possible to be able to see the already added values listed somewhere?

```js
okAndMore = new Button("Add & More");
   okAndMore.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       String name = nameBox.getText();
       if (name.length() > 0) {
         items.add(name);
         statusLbl.setText(name + " added");
       }
       nameBox.setText("");
       nameBox.setFocus(true);
     }
   });
```

Comment: Aren't the previously added values in items list?

Comment: Yeah they are e.g., like this:  `List <String> items = new ArrayList <String>();` But the problem is to display this when user enters more than one values in a textbox ...